# Updating a table using SSIS and OLE DB Command

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-update, oledb

I think this is so far the strangest problem I have had by using SSIS. I'm trying to update a table in SQL Server with some data from an Oracle database. I need to update some columns, one of them is numeric, just like in the source. But when the process finishes all the rows have been updated successfully except for those where the value should be 10, instead of that I've got a 0 as an answer. And this is happening only with this value, the others are correct.

[image]

[image]

This is the UPDATE used in the OLEDB Command:

```
UPDATE 
PEN
SET 
CEN= ?,
AR = ?
WHERE 
PE = ? AND
SU = ? AND
SO = ?
```

What could be happening to have this result?

Comment: If the source value for that row as 11 instead of 10, what value gets into Oracle?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the UPDATE query from your OLE DB Command?   Also, in the advanced properties of your source component, what is the DT datatype of BA?